# Can any local complete intersection subvariety be an intersection of smooth hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, deformation-theory

Let $Z$ be a local complete intersection subscheme of dimension $m$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2m+1}$. Let $P$ be the Hilbert polynomial of $Z$. Denote by $\operatorname{Hilb}_P$ the Hilbert scheme of local complete intersection subschemes with Hilbert polynomial $P$. Is it true that for a generic subscheme $Z'$ in $\operatorname{Hilb}_P$, $I(Z')$ can be generated by polynomials that define smooth hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{2m+1}$ i.e., does there exists polynomials $P_1, ..., P_n$ such that $I(Z')=(P_1,...,P_n)$ and the zero locus of $P_i$ is smooth for all $i$?

A slightly weaker condition would be to ask if a generic hypersurface in $\operatorname{pr}_2 \operatorname{Hilb}_{P,Q}$ is smooth where $\operatorname{Hilb}_{P,Q}$ is the flag Hilbert scheme of pairs $(Z \subset X)$ where $Z$ is a local complete intersection subscheme of dimension $m$ with Hilbert polynomial $P$ contained is a hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2m+1}$ with Hilbert polynomial $Q$ and $\operatorname{pr}_2$ denotes the natural projection map.

Comment: A necessary condition is that the tangent space at any point $P\in Z$  has dimension $\le 2m$.

Comment: @Rita:  That is what I was thinking as well, but I cannot think of a local complete intersection with a singular point of embedding dimension $2m+1$ for which I can prove the same is true after a generic deformation (I have been trying to produce "rigid" nonreduced structures on a smooth scheme of dimension $m$, but the computations are beyond me).  Since you are an expert on this, are there configurations of subschemes (e.g., configurations of degree 6 Del Pezzo surfaces in `$\mathbb{P}^5$`) that are LCI of embedding dimension $2m+1$ and also "rigid"?

Comment: @Jason: I had not seen your comment earlier. Unfortunately, I have no idea.


Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer to the first question is no for the reason that a local complete intersection is pretty far from a complete intersection. Take $Z$ to be $3$ points in $\mathbb P^3$ which aren't on a line. Then the Hilbert scheme of local complete intersections is a dense open subset of the Hilbert scheme of $3$ points in $\mathbb P^3$. However, the complete intersections will have to be the intersection of a cubic hypersurface with two hyperplanes, for degree reasons. Thus, the complete intersections will all lie on a single line in $\mathbb P^3$, which is not true for 3 generic points.

If you assumed that $Z$ is a complete intersection, not just a local complete intersection, then what you want is probably true.

Comment: @Dustin: The OP does not ask whether $Z$ is a complete intersection.  He asks whether $Z$ is an intersection of some (presumably huge) number $n$ of smooth hypersurfaces.  The integer $n$ need not equal $m+1$, the codimension.  The answer to the question is yes for $Z$ any finite collection of reduced points in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  

Comment: @Starr: Is there some results when $Z$ is not zero dimensional?

Comment: @Jason Starr: probably everybody thinks the question is over an algebraically closed fields, but this is not stated explicitely in the OP. Over an imperfect field, a reduced point can not be contained in a smooth hypersurface if its residue field has too high inseparability degree. 

Comment: @Qing Liu:  The OP explicitly states that he is taking a *generic* element of the corresponding Hilbert scheme.  Thus the zero dimensional scheme will be smooth over the ground field.

Comment: @Jason Starr: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. 

Comment: yes we all assumed he meant complete intersection!

Comment: @QingLiu: Could you explain why it is true that a reduced point $x$ of a scheme $X$ over imperfect field $k$ can not be contained in a smooth hypersurface if its residue field has too high inseparability degree? If we take $X := \mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y])$ and $x$ with $\mathfrak{m}_x = (x^{p^n} - t, y)$ for some $t \in k$ which is not a $p$-th power, then $\kappa(x) = k(t^{\frac{1}{p^n}})$ can has arbitrary large inseparability degree, but $x \in V(y)$ which is obviously a smooth hypersurface. Or did I misinterpreted your comment?