# Points with residue fields having big inseparability degree cannot be contained in smooth hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, characteristic-p

Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme over imperfect field $k$ and $x \in X $ some (reduced) point with residue field $\kappa(x) = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ \mathfrak{m}_x$. How to check that if $\kappa(x)$ has "big enough inseparability degree" then no smooth hypersurface $Z \subset X$ can contain $x$. In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/112486) discussion Qing Liu wrote that

> Over an imperfect field, a reduced point can not be contained in a smooth hypersurface if its residue field has too high inseparability degree.

That's rather interesting interpretation of inseparability degree as obstruction measure to be contained in certain smooth subschemes.

We can assume $X= \text{Spec}(R)$ to be affine with local $R$ with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$. I'm not sure if it is really neccessary to assume moreover $R$ to be reduced. We have to show that if we assume $\kappa(x)$ has big enough inseparability degree over $k$, then there cannot exist some prime ideal $I \subset R$ contained in $\mathfrak{m}_x$ such that $R/I$ is smooth.

**Edit**: as Ben C's example shows there are examples where $x$ is contained in a hypersurface independently how big the inseparability degree of the residue field becomes. So it seems that presumably I misunderstood the quoted statement. Any suggestions how Qing Liu's statement should be interpreted correctly?

Comment: What about $X = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y])$ and $\mathfrak{m}_x = (x^{p^n} - t, y)$ where $t \in k$ is some element which is not a $p$-th power. Then $\kappa(x) = k(t^{\frac{1}{p^n}})$ but $x \in Z(y)$ which is a smooth hypersurface.

Comment: @BenC: Thank you, the counterexample obviously works. Do you perhaps know what Qing Liu could have meant there in the linked discussion, maybe I may have misinterpreted his statement there?

Comment: Probably I indeed misread the statement, sorry for confusion. I think it should be an existence statement that there exist a scheme $X$ over imperfect field $k$ which has a reduced point $x \in X$ which is not contained in any smooth hypersurface of $X$, if  its residue field has "too high inseparability degree." In turn, if the residue field of $x$ is separable over $k$, then one can *always* find a smooth hypersurface of $X$ containing $x$. At least this sounds like a more reasonable statement.

Comment: Do you maybe see how to construct such $X$ with such point $x$?

Comment: If $k$ is infinite and $X$ is quasi-projective, then every smooth point of $X$ lies in a smooth hypersurface by Bertini so you'd need $X$ to be highly singular.

Comment: @BenC: The application of Bertini is an interesting point in this context. 
If I now understand correctly what Qing Liu
wrote in linked discussion, then it suggests in turn
that if $X$ is variety over perfect base field $k$, then the 
phenomenon I described above cannot appear, that means
that under assumption $k$ perfect there always exist 
a smooth hyperplane $Z \subset X$ containing $x$.
Your argument shows that if $x$ assumed moreover to be smooth, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ 
quasi-projective and
$k$ infinite, we can invoke Bertini to find such a smooth hypersurface obtained exacty

Comment: exacty as hyperplane section of $X$ with a hyperplane
$H \subset \mathbb{P}^N$.


If we pose this reverse question that if $k$ is perfect, and 
we claim that then $x$ is contained in a smooth hyperplane, can we 
argue more 'elementary' without invoking Bertini? That means constructing
or at least check indirectly the existence of smooth hypersurface
containing $x$ with more 'elementary' tools?

Comment: The problem with Bertini 
is that firstly it not covers the case $k$ finite (finite fields
are always perfect), and secondly in the the situation when
it is applicable it gives a far much stronger statement not only
that there exist a smooth hypersurface containing $x$, but 
even more that this hypersurface comes as pullback of a 
hyperplane, and that's a very strong statement, not every (smooth)
hypersurface of $X$ appear in that way.

Comment: This suggest that it might be
possible to find a smooth hypersurface containing $x$ with 'less effort' if we not require this
additional strong condition that it comes from a hyperplane 
in ambient projective space.

Comment: Bertini produces a regular hypersurface, but it is not smooth in general when the base field is imperfect.

Comment: @JunKoizumi: Yes that's true. My concern was focussed on Liu's formulation *"too high"* in the statement that a reduced point can not be contained in a smooth hypersurface if its residue field $\kappa(x)$ has "too high" inseparability degree. It sounds not only like a binary condition - like is residue field inseparable or separable - but moreover like a kind of "scaling" or "measure" for difficulty of how hard it is in some sense to find a smooth hyperplane containing this point $x$ depending of inseparability degree of the residue field of this point.

Comment: as Ben's example above shows this holds definitely not for every point with arbtrary high inseparabality degree, therefore I'm  confused about what Qing Liu wanted  really to tell there using the formulation of "too high" inseparability degree. Surely there exist regular, but not smooth hypersurfaces even with "small" inseprability degree of the base field. So I not see how does it matter if the residue field of the considered point has "small or big" inseparability degree, it seems that it only matters that it is inseparable. That's why I not understand Qing Liu's formulation there. Any idea?