# Obstruction for points to be contained in smooth hypersurfaces in tterms of inseparability degree of residue field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, characteristic-p

Let $k$ be an *imperfect field* of char $p>0$ and
$x \in \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be closed point of projective space.

In [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/q/112486) Qing Liu wrote that

> Over an imperfect field, a reduced point can not be contained
> in a smooth hypersurface if its residue field has "too
> high" inseparability degree.

I'm not sure in which sense this statement it is true.
The central point there which
confuses me, is that it seems to suggest that the inseparability
degree of the residue field of $x$ gives a kind of
"measure" how difficult it is to find a smooth hypersurface
$V \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ containing $x$.

Problems:

1. Which relevance has here the posed assumption that $x$
   should be reduced? All points of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ are reduced,
   so I not understand why it should be extra added. Maybe there is
   some crucial relevance I not see up to now.
2. How to interpret it? It seems that Qing Liu's statement on
   high inseparabality degree of the residue field is a necessary,
   not sufficient statement
   for the property to be not contained in a smooth hypersurface,
   since there are of course points
   $x \in \mathbb{P}^n_k$ with residue field $\kappa(x)$ of arbitrary
   big inseparability degree beeing contained in a hyperplane. Or maybe it's a statement for *general* hypersurfaces containing $x$, I don't know, that's just a guess; cp. also with point 3 below)

Here a counterexample: the point $x \in \mathrm{Spec}(k[w,v]) 
\subset \mathrm{Proj}(k[W,V, U])$ (with $w:=W/U, v:=V/U$ local coords)
associated to maximal
ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x := (w^{p^n} - t, v) \subset k[w,v]$
where $t \in k$, the residue field is
$\kappa(x) = k(t^{\frac{1}{p^n}})$, but $x$ is obviously
contained in smooth hyperplane $(V=0)$.

3. For every point $x \in \mathbb{P}^n_k$
   Bertini's theorem would give us at least a
   *regular* hypersurface containing $x$, but it is known
   that over imperfect field not every regular scheme is smooth.
   But that's a binary condition: imperfect base field
   implies that regular not equivalent to smooth.

What does it have to do with *how big* the inseparability degree
of the residue field is, and not just that it is not separable? If I'm not missing the point it
seems that Qing Liu want to say that
the obstruction for a regular hypersurface containing
the point $x$ to be even smooth sits in the
inseparability degree of the residue field of $x$. But is it true
(at least as a statement for general hypersurfaces, since
point 2 gives counterexple) and how
to see it?

Comment: The statement needs to be clarified (as with many, *many* such statements in Qing Liu's book).  For a finite field extension $L/k$, if the $L$-vector space dimension of $\Omega_{L/k}$ equals $r$, then $r$ is the smallest dimension of a smooth $k$-scheme $V$ that contains a closed point with residue field $L$ (as a $k$-extension).  In particular, if a smooth hypersurface $V$ in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ contains a closed point with residue field $L$, then $n\geq 1+r$.

Comment: So for a concrete example, look at points like $P = [s^{1/p}:t^{1/p}:1]$ in $\mathbf P^2_{[x:y:z]}$ over $k = \mathbf F_p(s,t)$. It cannot be contained in a smooth curve since $\Omega_{\kappa(P)/k}$ is 2-dimensional: the point $z$ is cut out by the polynomials $f = x^p-s$ and $g = y^p-s$ in the affine chart $D(z) = \mathbf A^2_{(x,y)}$, so the map $\Omega_{\mathbf A^2/k}|_P \to \Omega_{\kappa(P)/k}$ is an isomorphism as $\mathrm df = \mathrm dg = 0$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: and this condition follows immediately from the analysis of the exact sequence $\Omega^1_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/k} \otimes \kappa(x) \to \Omega^1_{\kappa(x)/k} \to \Omega^1_{\kappa(x)/ \mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \to 0$ induced by $k \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \kappa(x)$ + application of criterion of smoothness to right term, right?

Comment: And so in order to archieve such $x$ we are looking for residue field $\kappa(x)$ such that the purely inseparable part of  $\kappa(x)/k$ has much more generators than $n-1$, since for purely inseparable extension $F/E$ the $F$-dimension of $\Omega^1_{F/E}$ equals the minimal number of generators of $F$ as $E$-algebra

Comment: typo: smoothness criterion applied to *left* term...